# Join Two Tables and Replace Values Where Conditions Meet

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to come with an expression to join two tables (the first two) to get something like the third one.

I want to SELECT 'Sitepage' and 'Medium' and JOIN the first two tables ON the rows where the RIGHT 5 characters are matching between 'Sitepage' and 'Campaign ID'. Additionally, IF there is a match, THEN 'Program' will REPLACE 'Medium'. What would be the Syntax?

```
Sitepage | Medium                 
xyz.com/campaign=12345 | A           
xyz.com/campaign=23456 | C        

Campaign ID | Program                 
12345 | B           

Sitepage | Medium                 
xyz.com/campaign=12345 | B           
xyz.com/campaign=23456 | C
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq35n.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I based my answer off of @Juan's, but I had to make some adjustments to get it to work.

```
SELECT
  SitePage, COALESCE(t2.Program, t1.Medium) as Medium
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON RIGHT(t1.Sitepage, 5) = COALESCE(t2.`Campaign ID`, -1);
```

@Abhik was heading in the right direction too. It's more generic than the one above, which assumes that the last 5 characters of `SitePage` will be the only pertinent ones. With that said, I would have gone with...

```
SELECT
  SitePage, COALESCE(t2.Program, t1.Medium) as Medium
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Sitepage,'=',-1)
    = COALESCE(t2.`Campaign ID`, -1);
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afaa0/13)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring_index` and then update by join

```
update table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.`Campaign ID` = substring_index(t1.`Sitepage`,'=',-1)
set t1.`Medium` = t2.`Program`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SitePage, ISNULL(t2.Program, t1.Medium) as Medium
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON RIGHT(t1.Medium, 5) = t2.CampaignId
```

That should do the trick. Left Join on the expresion you want, when there is a match, Program will not be null so you can pick it up, otherwise pick medium. If your table2 allows null on Program you may need to tweak this.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the answer I'm looking for, but I get "Function 'isnull(string,string)' is not declared" when parsing the function. How can I fix that?

Comment: Yeah, use Coalesce. I mainly work on MS SQL Server and we have ISNULL there :)